# Test if tetrahedron is inscribed by a sphere

Tags: geometry

Say I want to check if some linear geom object (segment, tetrahedron,.. ) is fully inscribed by the sphere.

I am thinking of testing if all the vertices of the linear object lies inside sphere and if so the object itself 
is inside the sphere.

Is there a possibility that this test fails for linear objects?

Also, is there a fast algorithm to do this.

Comment: Are you given a specific sphere?  Or do you want to know if it is inscribed in some (presumably unique) sphere?

Comment: any sphere. say I have a environment with tetrahedrons and I query a sphere as a range query to find all the tetrahedrons fully inscribed by the range(sphere).

Comment: Be careful. [The tetrahedron is a hermaphrodite](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36/conversation/danger-of-tetrahedrons).

Comment: @GustavoBandeira what does that mean?

Comment: @cowboy Nothing. It was just something I've read in a book.

Comment: @GustavoBandeira btw, it is interesting. :)

Answer (score 1):

That test will work if the object you're testing is convex. Common objects like line segments, triangles and tetrahedra *are* convex, so you're OK.

For more complex objects, like Bezier curves and surfaces, you can easily construct the convex hull and use that in your test.

One algorithm to test whether a vertex lies within a sphere is the obvious one -- just test to see if the distance to the sphere center is less than the sphere radius. You can avoid the square rooot by testing squared distance, instead of distance, and this will give you a small performance gain, probably.

If you're testing a large number of objects, the best way to get speed on a modern computer is through parallelism -- obviously you can test several objects simultaneously on several different processors.

Comment: yeah. true. I do not work with non linear elements (splines, etc.) thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: even for concave objects this works, isnt it? basically if all the vertices are inside, you can not have a segment which goes from one vertice to the other making the object concave be outside sphere as the segments are linear.

Comment: True. I didn't give much thought to non-convex objects.